# VSCodeのキーボードショートカットを変更する拡張機能で、インストールしただけでは有効にならないキーアサインを一括で有効にする方法はありますか

Tags: vscode, key-mapping, key-binding

MacOSでVSCodeを使い始めようとしてまず初めにキーアサインをEmacs風にする拡張機能をインストールしました。具体的には次の2つを試しています。

- (たぶん)Emacs Keymap Improved (アンインストールしてしまったので記憶が定かでありませんがEmacs Keymap派生の拡張機能)
- Awesome Emacs Keymap

どちらの拡張機能も、インストールしただけでは、一部のキーアサイン(例えばM-<など)は有効になるものの、既存のキーアサインと衝突する多くのキーアサイン(例えばC-eなど)は有効にならないようです。
VSCodeの「キーボードショートカット」エディタで、キーアサインの衝突を検出する方法は学びましたが、拡張機能の作者が用意したEmacs風のキーアサインの多くを実現するためには、拡張機能をインストールしただけでは足りず、自分の手でひとつひとつキーアサインの衝突を解消していかなければいけないのでしょうか。

もっと簡単な方法があるはずだとかんがえて様々な検索ワードで検索しましたが、有用な情報はみつからず、今の所、自分の手でキーアサインの衝突を解消するほかないのか、と観念しかけているところです。

なにかもっと「簡単な方法」があれば教えて下さい。そんな方法はないんだよ、みんなこうやっているんだよ、という情報も有用ですので教えて下さい。とりあえずMacOSで試していますが、WindowsやLinuxでもVSCodeを使いたいので、それらの環境にspecificな情報もあると助かります。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、自己解決しました。

質問冒頭にある「インストールしただけでは、一部のキーアサイン(例えばM-<など)は有効になるものの、既存のキーアサインと衝突する多くのキーアサイン(例えばC-eなど)は有効にならないようです。」というのは私の誤認でした。MacOSのシステム環境設定でCommandキーとCtrlキーの入れ替えなどをやっていたのを忘れていたため、あたかもキーアサインが有効になっていないように見えていただけでした。キーアサイン変更ユーティリティ(Karabiner-Elements)を使い、VSCodeでこの入れ替えをしないようにしたところ、期待通りのEmacs風キーアサインが使えるようになりました。

どうも失礼いたしました。